# How can I combine a Huggingface tokenizer and a BERT-based model in onnx?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, onnx, huggingface-tokenizers

**Problem description:**

I have a model based on BERT, with a classifier layer on top. I want to export it to ONNX, but to avoid issues on the side of the 'user' of the onnx model, I want to export the entire pipeline, including tokenization, as a ONNX model. However, this requires a basic string as input type, which I believe ONNX does not support.

**The Model:**

```
class BertClassifier(nn.Module):
    """
    Class defining the classifier model with a BERT encoder and a single fully connected classifier layer.
    """
    def __init__(self, dropout=0.5, num_labels=24):
        super(BertClassifier, self).__init__()

        self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(768, num_labels)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.best_score = 0

    def forward(self, input_id, mask):
        _, pooled_output = self.bert(input_ids=input_id, attention_mask=mask, return_dict=False)
        output = self.relu(self.linear(self.dropout(pooled_output)))

        return output
```

**The Tokenizer:**

```
def get_tokenizer(chosen_model):
    # chosen_model = 'bert_base_uncased'
    return AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(chosen_model)
```

**Combined Pipeline:**

```
class OnnxBertModel(nn.Module):
    """
    Model wrapper for onnx. Allows user to only provide a string as input. Output is a list of class probabilities
    """
    def __init__(self, dropout=0.5, num_labels=24):
        super(OnnxBertModel, self).__init__()

        self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(768, num_labels)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.best_score = 0
        self.tokenizer = get_tokenizer('bert-base-uncased')

    def forward(self, input_string):
        input_tokens = self.tokenizer(input_string,
                       padding='max_length', max_length=512, truncation=True,
                       return_tensors="pt")
        mask = input_tokens['attention_mask']
        input_id = input_tokens['input_ids'].squeeze(1)
        _, pooled_output = self.bert(input_ids=input_id, attention_mask=mask, return_dict=False)
        output = self.relu(self.linear(self.dropout(pooled_output)))
        return output
```

**Additional code to export:**

```
model = OnnxBertModel(num_labels=len(labels))
torch.onnx.export(model, ex_string, 'tryout.onnx', export_params=True, do_constant_folding=False)
```

The last call does not work due to the string typing.

Comment: What type of error are you getting when you do the string type input? My model was able to export if I converted the output to a string in the forward method, but getting errors further down stream when I do the inference runtime.